# How can I make my SVG scrollable along X-axis as it stays under as div and overflows the screen width in HTML?

Tags: html, css, svg

Consider my Code here:

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  max-width: 500px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<p>Present Here</p>
<div>
  <svg width="400" height="400">
    <line x1="0" y1="250" x2="300" y2="250" style="stroke:rgb(80,80,80);stroke-width:1" />
      </svg>
</div>
```

I just want my `div`, when gets overflown [as the screen sizes is less than that of 500px] to be scrollable along X-axis. But it just does not happen. I find the whole body to be scrollable. When I scroll, even the `Present Here` paragraph shifts from it's position, that I obviously do not want. I just want the `svg` to get shifted with its scrollbar.

What changes do I need?
[Here][1] I have the code.

Answer (score 0):

You set `width: 500px;` so when the body is narrower than 500px, the div is wider than the body, and the body overflows.

The div is never narrower than 500px, so the 400px wide SVG will never overflow it.

Set `width: auto` (which is the default so you could just not set the `width` at all) to make the div take up the available horizontal space to a maximum of the `max-width`.